# How do I decrease the screen brightness in f.lux?

Tags: brightness, f.lux

I've heard that, in addition to controlling screen temperature, you can use f.lux to decrease the *brightness* of your screen. However, I couldn't find a brightness option in settings, nor could I find any mention of the feature on the [official website](https://justgetflux.com/).

[image: f.lux options menu]

How do I control my screen brightness in f.lux?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can increase brightness with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and decrease brightness with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd>.

[image: dimming screen with f.lux]

Answer (score 9):

As the OP's answer specifies, you can increase and decrease brightness with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd>.

However, on Windows, these hotkeys were disabled by default for me. You can activate these by clicking on the three-horizontal-bar menu and selecting "Options and Smart Lighting...". Here, tick the box to enable hotkeys.

[image: f.lux Options window]